Question on how Microled and Nanoled are designed differently
I have asked the following question in SuperUser.SE. If I asked the question on this site would it be closed?

How are NanoLED and MicroLED computer screens designed
differently?
Mokubai said that

You can clearly see the difference just by looking at the LED stages.
One has single colour elements, the other shows a lot of little dots

I don't undestand what single colour elements vs a lot (some tens
after focusing on a particular part of each of the 3 RGB element) of
little dots means. Does this imply that in Microled each band
(element) is made up of one single pixel?

The NanoLED trademark seems to indicate that the issue is probably marketing, and not different design or materials: 


I don't see a difference since both are allegedly self-emmissive and turn electricity into light
Other than the different emmiter name, I can't see anything different.



I think the question is a question of design (probably circuit design
too since panels are a circuit of LEDs) because the differences
between these 2 tecnologies may be due to design as suggested by
Mokubai when they said

just look closely at the image. You can clearly see the difference
just by looking at the LED stages. One has single colour elements, the
other shows a lot of little dots.


Other tags like led, display, diode are self evident.
Maybe optics, optoelectronics
The question has nothing to do with the displays' usage (I just had a computer screen in mind) People unproblematically ask about the working principle I am asking about the science behind any alleged difference.
Examples of such questions
Do "blown" fluorescent lights still use electricity?
What is LED starter?
Magnetron Working Principle
My question (that I would like to ask in the main site) could be reworded into
Is there anything scientific behind why they might show pictures differently or is it just marketing?

Please don't cross post. Questions should exist on one site only. This question would likely be closed as it isn't a design question.

I don't understand what you mean not a design question. Are the examples I gave above design questions? Is the problem incorrect tagging? None of these 3 questions were tagged with design or circuit design. And how is it not a design question if the difference (the answer) is something along the line "One has single colour elements, the other shows a lot of little dots."

This is an EE question according to the fact that most photonics research is done in EE depts at universities, in addition to Materials depts.

I suspect he reposted it because there was no answer as to where he can post the question.  I would like to answer this question but it looks like he got the runaround all over SE and may never have been told where to post the question!

@Demis https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/62257/how-are-nanoled-and-microled-computer-screens-designed-differently
